# Variable not available at Spyder's Variable Explorer when naming it with upper case only

Tags: python, spyder

I'm getting the following problem using Spyder:

If I name a variable just with upper case letters, it is not shown at the Variable Explorer window.

For example, if I name a variable like:
Var = 1, it is in the Variable Explorer.

Otherwise, if I name it like:
VAR = 1, it is not shown there.

Anyone know why is that and if there is any way to fix it?

(ps: please, I know that I could just "not name them like that", but that's not what I'm asking)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am a newbie in Python and Spyder but I think I can help you. According with the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

"Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL".

I guess that Spyder uses this convention. If this is the case, the variable explorer does not support constants. [The Spyder 2.3 documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/variableexplorer.html) have a list of the types of objects supported and constants are not included:

1. Pandas DataFrames and TimeSeries
2. NumPy arrays and matrices
3. PIL/Pillow images
4. datetime dates
5. Integers
6. Floats
7. Complex numbers
8. Lists
9. Dictionaries
10. Tuples
11. Strings

Hope this helps you.

**UPDATE:** I have just found an Options icon in the vertical bar at the right of the Variables explorer which allows you to enable/disable the uppercase variables.